# ReorderableListView order doesn't change

Tags: flutter, dart

I am usiing a ReorderableListView to give a feature of managing the list order of models
I am using a ChangeNotifier class with provider package to provide the list to sub-widgets and manipulate the value ofcourse.
I am replacing 2 elements on the list(drag and drop abilty of reorderable list) and when i do that i am call a function inside the changenotifer provider to replace 2 value. and its doing its job after i replace 2 value the widget the rebuilds so as the reorderablelistview widget BUT even if the list updated order of the reorderablelistview doesn't change its always shows the first order version of the list

```
final class _AllExercisesColumnState extends State<AllExercisesColumn>
    with AllExercisesColumnOperation {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final exercises =
        Provider.of<WorkoutModelProvider>(context).workoutModel.exercises;
    print(exercises);
    print('build');
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: onDragDrop,
      children: exercisesWidgets(exercises),
    );
  }
}
```

```
mixin AllExercisesColumnOperation on State<AllExercisesColumn> {
  //late Map<int, ExerciseModel> exercises;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  /// This function will return the all exercises as
  /// EditExerciseDefaultsContainer List<widget>
  List<Widget> exercisesWidgets(List<ExerciseModel> exercises) {
    final widgetList = <Widget>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < exercises.length; i++) {
      print(exercises[i]);
      print(ValueKey(i));
      widgetList.add(
        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          key: ValueKey(i),
          subtitle: EditExerciseDefaultsContainer(
            exerciseKeyId: i,
            exerciseModel: exercises[i],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return widgetList;
  }

  void onDragDrop(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    Provider.of<WorkoutModelProvider>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    ).change2ExercisesIndex(
      firstIndex: oldIndex,
      secondIndex: newIndex,
    );
  }
}
```

```
part of 'workout_program_editor_view.dart';

/// Workout model provider for managing state between widgets
final class WorkoutModelProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  /// base constructor
  /// [_workoutId] Cache key value of saved workout model
  /// [_workoutModel] model will provide
  WorkoutModelProvider(this._workoutId, this._workoutModel) {
    _firstExerciseList = List.from(workoutModel.exercises);
  }

  /// The key id of the exercise saved in cache
  final int _workoutId;

  /// first workout model
  late final List<ExerciseModel> _firstExerciseList;

  final WorkoutModel _workoutModel;

  /// The key id of the exercise saved in cache
  int get workoutId => _workoutId;

  /// getter for workout model
  WorkoutModel get workoutModel => _workoutModel;

  /// this function will change the given [model] exercise model
  /// on specified index in [_workoutModel]'s exercise map
  void changeExercise({required int key, required ExerciseModel model}) {
    _workoutModel.exercises[key] = model;
  }

  /// this function will add a new exercise on [_workoutModel],s exercise
  /// map with given [exerciseName]
  void addExercise({required String exerciseName}) {
    _workoutModel.exercises.add(
      ExerciseModel(
        exerciseName: exerciseName,
        defaultSetCount: 1,
        defaultRepCount: 1,
        defaultWeightCount: 1.25,
      ),
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// This function will replace 2 exercises index's 
  void change2ExercisesIndex({
    required int firstIndex,
    required int secondIndex,
  }) {
    if (firstIndex < secondIndex) {
      secondIndex--;
    }

    final tile = _workoutModel.exercises.removeAt(firstIndex);

    _workoutModel.exercises.insert(secondIndex, tile);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// this function will restore [_workoutModel]'s exercises with
  /// first version of [_workoutModel]'s exercise which is stored in
  /// the [_firstExerciseList]
  void restoreDefault() {
    _workoutModel.exercises.clear();
    _workoutModel.exercises.addAll(_firstExerciseList);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

output:

```
flutter: build
flutter: ExerciseModel(exerciseName: exercise 1, defaultSetCount: 1, defaultRepCount: 1, defaultWeightCount: 1.25)
flutter: [<0>]
flutter: ExerciseModel(exerciseName: exercise 2, defaultSetCount: 1, defaultRepCount: 1, defaultWeightCount: 1.25)
flutter: [<1>]
flutter: [ExerciseModel(exerciseName: exercise 2, defaultSetCount: 1, defaultRepCount: 1, defaultWeightCount: 1.25), ExerciseModel(exerciseName: exercise 1, defaultSetCount: 1, defaultRepCount: 1, defaultWeightCount: 1.25)]
flutter: build
flutter: ExerciseModel(exerciseName: exercise 2, defaultSetCount: 1, defaultRepCount: 1, defaultWeightCount: 1.25)
flutter: [<0>]
flutter: ExerciseModel(exerciseName: exercise 1, defaultSetCount: 1, defaultRepCount: 1, defaultWeightCount: 1.25)
flutter: [<1>]
```

[video of the problem](https://youtube.com/shorts/5O7VfOHj_cI?feature=share)

I tried to rebuild to widget but even if i do the list ordering is not right.

Comment: What is change2ExercisesIndex doing?

Comment: @Csisanyi I edited the context basicly added my provider model u can look at bottom of the provider model for the function. its basily changes 2 exercises' index